# multiple word search in flutter

Tags: algorithm, flutter, dart

Suppose I have a recipe called `Garlic parmesan butter`. I need to return an object when the appropriate name has been found.
Now in a simple ad-hoc solution I can search in the following way:

```
class SearchRecipe {
  late RecipeModel recipe;
  RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Store.instance.getAllRecipes().length; i++) {
      if (suggestion == Store.instance.getAllRecipes()[i].recipeName) {
        return Store.instance.getAllRecipes()[i];
      }
    }
    return recipe;
  }
}
```

But I need a simple way where if the user types in `Garlic butter` I need to return the object associated with the `Garlic Paremesan butter`.

How can I do it?

**Edit:** I should've clarified that I'm working with a List of objects. So the `Store.instance.getAllRecipes()` basically returns a `List<RecipeModel>`.

**Update 1:** This is what I've written:

```
class SearchRecipe {
  //late RecipeModel recipe;
  RecipeModel returnRecipe(String? suggestion) {
    List<RecipeModel> results = [];

    suggestion!.split(' ').forEach((s) {
      results.addAll(Store.instance
          .getAllRecipes()
          .where((element) => element.recipeName!.contains(s)));
    });
    results = results.toSet().toList();

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      return results[i];
    }
    return results[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try .contains() ?

Comment: @pskink I actually integrated trie for prefix matching and the solution you provided works alone but not with the trie I implemented.  Would you like to see that? Maybe you'll get a better grasp at the problem I'm facing?

Comment: @pskink another issue is that I'm working with a list of object and not a list of Strings so I think I made some errors in that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String search = 'Garlic butter';
List<String> list = [
  'Garlic Paremesan butter',
  'Butter',
  'Garlic',
  'Butter Garlic',
  'Paremesan',
  'Stackoverflow'
];

List<String> results = [];

search.split(' ').forEach((s) {
  results.addAll(list.where((element) => element.contains(s)));
});

// Avoid repeated values
results = results.toSet().toList();
```

Comment: not returning `Bengali Lamb curry`  when I write `Bengali curry`. I've edited my post please let me know if I'm doing it right

Comment: Just did a test and it worked great. Write the following function and give it a try https://pastebin.com/ScGPMD5z

Comment: Hi @linesOfCode. Pardon my stupidity. But as you can see I have a list of objects and before even matching the recipe names with user query I have to iterate over the `recipe` length. So the way you've written you're code doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: Why don't you then do a simple `for` loop from your `Store.instance.getAllRecipes()` and put the `recipeName` inside of the `list` variable I gave as an example? Then everything would work like my sample.

Comment: hey that worked thanks a lot. But When I types in `Bengali Curry` it should return only `Bengali Lamb Curry` but it returns both `Bengali Lamb Curry` & `Malai Lamb Curry`
I assume it's happening because both recipe has curry in them? So do I need some sort of ranking?

Here's the code that I'm using. You helped quite a lot so I can't ask any more from you but if you have any suggestion after looking at the code please do let me know.
Link: https://pastebin.com/1YzAW7SN

Comment: 1. You need to apply some criteria (ranking is good) 2. You should remove (trim) all the before & after spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Split the user input at spaces. Then you have a list. You can check the list and depending on your preference implement a variety of behaviors.

You can match if all words in the list are found. You can return if at least one of the words is matched.

You could give preference to more contained words or you could check the order of words.

In either case you would also not check for equality but use a function like includes / contains to check whether the searched word is part of the name.

(Checking the order could be done by remembering which words you already identified and only searching after the words that were found. In your example you would find ‘garlic’ and after that you would just look through ‘paremesan Butter’ and try to find ‘butter’)

Answer (score 1):

first split the input text

```
var string = "Hello world!";
string.split(" ");  
// ['Hello', 'world!'];
```

then iterate over each word in above array and check whether the above
Store.instance.getAllRecipes()[i].recipeName   contains above word.

```
if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(str))
{
      //remaining code
}
```

try contains method.

```
.contains()
```

Answer (score 1):

This how I am doing multiline search queries through a tabular list of data. `column[3]` contains the words I am checking against.

The first search query is searched through the entire "mainTable".
If a search word has been found, a filtered list is used which only holds items that contain the search word.
The remaining search words are then checked against the filtered list, which is further reduced if subsequent matching words are found.
If the first search word cannot be found, the next search word will be used.

```
List<List<dynamic>> mainTable; // Your data table
List<List<dynamic>> filterList = List.empty(); // List of search results

void SearchWordbyWord(String value){

  filterList = mainTable;

  if (value.isEmpty || value == "") {
    //refresh page
    return;
  }

  bool found = false;
  String search = value.toUpperCase(); // Make sure search query case matches dataTable items

  List<String> searchWords = search.split(' ').where((String s) => s.isNotEmpty).toList();
  for (int i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++) {
    if (!found) {
      // Need to check if ANY word in searchWords can be found in the list
      var first = mainTable.where((List<dynamic> column) =>
          column[3].split(' ').where((String s) => s.isNotEmpty).toList().contains(searchWords[i])).toList();

      // Use filtered list of items that match the search string
      if (first.isNotEmpty) {
        filterList = first;
        found = true;
      }
    }
    else {
      // Check if any remaining search words are inside the filtered list
      var refined = filterList.where((List<dynamic> column) =>
          column[3].split(' ').where((String s) => s.isNotEmpty).toList().contains(searchWords[i])).toList();

      if (refined.isNotEmpty) {
        filterList = refined;
      }
    }
  }

  if (!found){
    filterList = List.empty();
  }

  // REFRESH PAGE OTHERWISE LIST WILL NOT VISUALLY UPDATE
}
```

NOTES:

The major trade off for this method is that the first search query which is found influences the result of the remaining search queries.
In my case this works out fine as I am using this to find products that often involve multiline strings with varying degrees of sentence structures.
Re-arranging the order of search words will return what you are looking for in most cases.
This search function does not check for character similarities, it will only check against whole strings seperated by whitespaces.

e.g.

```
wordsList = [apple, zuchinni, orange, lime], [orange, zuchinni, plum, banana], [lime, plum, orange, lemon], [lemon, banana, zuchinni, carrot]                        
    
search1 = "apple orange banana"
result -> [apple, zuchinni, orange, lime]
                
search2 = "banana apple orange"
result -> [orange, zuchinni, plum, banana], [lemon, banana, zuchinni, carrot]

search3 = "orange banana apple"
result -> [apple, zuchinni, orange, lime], [orange, zuchinni, plum, banana], [lime, plum, orange, lemon]
```

More results are returned if orange is the first search query as orange is more common inside the wordsList array.