# Search item from list in multiple element

Tags: flutter, dart

I have search field that filter my list and it works fine, but I want to filter list by multiple elements

My list:

```
List<Product> _p = [
  Product(
   title : 'P1',
   info : 'just Football',
   seller : 'me',
  ),
  Product(
   title : 'P2',
   info : 'just Football',
   seller : 'other',
  ),
]
```

filter method

```
List<Product> filterByText(text){
    return _p.where((element) =>
        element.title.contains(text) ||
        element.info.contains(text) ||
        element.seller.contains(text)
  ).toList();
}
```

I want, when I type `Football other` in `TextFormField`, to get this item:

```
Product(
 title : 'P2',
 info : 'just Football',
 seller : 'other',
),
```

Instead, it returns an empty list. It worked when I type just `other`. How can I filter with multiple elements by single string?

Comment: make the text to lowercase both of them e.g element.titlte!.toLowercase().contains(text.toLowercase()),

Comment: you can change input text to list of string and then find

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you give me example how can make it

Comment: on my theory, if you type `Football other`, it will get every item that contain thes two words. perhaps it will be checking positional

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple word search in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852522/multiple-word-search-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I'll go with one approach:

You can implement `Product`'s `toString()` method like so:

```dart
@override
String toString() {
  return '$title $info $seller'; // You can add other fields here if needed.
}
```

Now, implement a fuzzy search, for `filterByText`. To do this, you can use an existing package like https://pub.dev/packages/fuzzywuzzy.

```dart
List<Product> filterByText(text) {
  return extractTop(
    query: text,
    choices: _p,
    cutoff: 10, // You can choose another cutoff
    // You can choose another number of results
    // or show all using a different method
    limit: 4,
    getter: (x) => x.toString(),
  ).map((result) => result.choice).toList();
}
```

You don't have to necessarily implement `toString()` you can also just write `'${x.title} ${x.info} ${x.seller}'` in the getter field of `extractTop` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can break down the initial search query into words and then search all the words. Combine the results at the end.

```dart
String searchQuery = 'Some Query With Multiple Words';
List<String> queryWords = searchQuery.split(' ');
List<Product> results = [];
for(String word in queryWords){
  final filterResult = filterByText(word);
  results.addAll(filterResult);
}

results = results.toSet().toList(); // to remove duplicates
```

Please ensure you override the `==` for class `Product`.

This might help you further: [multiple word search in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67852522/multiple-word-search-in-flutter)

Comment: i got error in ```(...filterResult)```

Comment: does `filterByText()` return `List<Product>`? If yes, then I've updated the code accordingly